# SharePoint 2010 Excel xlsm file won't save to local computer

Tags: sharepoint-online, excel

I'm having a problem troubleshooting an issue on SharePoint 2010.

Users with Read only permissions via NT Authority/Authenticated users are having problems saving a local copy of a xlsm as a local copy . I'm Site Collection Administrator and I also have the same issue.

The file is located in a library that has other 4 xlsm files. Out of the 5 files only 3 are able to be downloaded locally, the others when I try to "Save As" I get the Windows "Save As" dialog but when selecting the type of file format I only get "all files" type. The other 3 xlsm give me various file formats to save as.

Even when trying to save the file with a "all files" format it doesn't save locally.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why but an alternative is to map your SharePoint site as a network drive so that you can access the files from windows explorer. Then, you can just copy and paste the file to a location you want.

Follow the steps outlined here: http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/map-a-sharepoint-document-library-as-a-network-drive